# Образование слов

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Язык постоянно пополняется новыми словами, которые образуются разными способами.
Какое из данных слов образовано иначе, чем остальные?

- сахарница (сахар/ниц/а)
- сахарница (сахар/ниц/а)
- мыльница (мыль/ниц/а)
- супница (суп/ниц/а)
- пудреница (пудр/ен/иц/а)
- вольница (воль/н/иц/а)

*Морфемный разбор по словарю Тихонова*

Не могу разобраться - все слова образованы суффиксальным способом, к двум из них прибавилось 2 суффикса. Какой же тогда будет образован иначе, чем другие?

Comment: Вы из какого учебника брали это задание?

Comment: Я в этом не разбираюсь, но может всё-таки моё предположение верно, что надо обратить внимание на буквы, следующие за корнем.

Comment: _Анастасия9А: пудр/ен/иц/а... Морфемный разбор по словарю Тихонова_ === **Не верю** в то, что у Тихонова "ен/иц"! Может, всё-таки "е/ниц" ("е" -- интерфикс)?

Comment: Нет, почему-то ен/иц.

Answer (score 4):

Первые четыре образованы от существительных с помощью суфф -ниц-(-ениц-) со значением предмета.

сахарница (сахар/ниц/а)-сахар+ниц(а)

мыльница (мыль/ниц/а)-мыл(о)+ ниц(а)

супница (суп/ниц/а) - суп+ниц(а)

пудреница (пудр/ен/иц/а) - пудр(а)+ ениц(а)  ениц=ен+иц

вольница (воль/н/иц/а)-вольн(ый)+иц(а) Вольница - группа вольных людей, образовано от прилагательного с помощью суфф. -иц-

Answer (score 3):

Пудра - пудреница (коробочка для пудры, суффикс ЕНИЦ

Сравнить: птица → птенец, первый → первенец, свояк → свояченица  – суффиксы ЕНЕЦ (мужской род) и ЕНИЦ (женский род) – единичные суффиксы с одной буквой Н.

Comment: Согласна с вашим мнением, но меня обескураживает тот факт, что в словарях написано 2 суффикса.

Comment: Вера, суффикс разный,допустим, но ведь  средство словообразования одинаковое  - суффиксальное.

Comment: У меня информация из Толкового словаря словообразовательных частиц Ефремовой: свояк - свояченица.  В слове "пудреница" сложный  словообразующий суффикс ЕНЕЦ, а в словарях, наверное, указываются элементарные суффиксы ЕН и ИЦ.

Comment: Может быть, имеется в виду. что схемы разные: 1) воля - вольный - вольница; 2) сахар - сахарница и т.д Получается, что слово  "воля" мотивировано прилагательным, а все остальные слова - существительными.